# How to add a single file from the inner folder into commit

Tags: git

[image]I have a folder lessons in which I initialized a git repo. There is another folder named lesson-1 in the folder lessons. I would like to add into my commit only files index.html and index.js but not the whole folder lesson-1

```
--lessons  git repo

  --lesson-1 
     -index.html
     -index.js`
```

I would like to include in my commit index.html and index.js.

I tried these commands

```
 git add lesson-1/index.js  lesson-1/index.js`
 git add ./lesson-1/index.js  ./lesson-1/index.js`
```

However, it still keeps pushing a folder lesson-1.

Comment: What other files exist in `lesson-1` folder?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No other files, only these two.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem then? What does "whole folder" mean?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It means lesson-1. When I push into git I see a folder lames lesson-1. I like to see two files instead.

Comment: Two files where? They're inside the folder `lesson-1` and when you add them to git they're in `lesson-1`. Why would we expect them not to be in the folder `lesson-1`? --- Git doesn't commit folders.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I attached a foto. Instead of a folder I want to push index.html and index.js.

Comment: The files are there inside the `lesson-1`. If you don’t want the folder, move them out of it. Then add and commit them outside of it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Do not pay attention at the name of the folder. In this case it can be lesson-3 or lesson-4. It for the sake of example.

Comment: yeah that’s fine. it doesn’t matter what the name of the folder is. Move the files outside of the folder, if you don’t want them in there. It’s not possible to have them both inside a folder locally and outside a folder when pushed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox But i have many folders in which there are files with the same name(index.html and index.js). So I can't move them from their folders.

Comment: then leave them alone. They still exist inside the folder. Click the folder and you should see them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Ok, I think I'll push folders, there's nothing wrong with it. I think the answer is that  what I precisely want cannot be achieved) At least, as far as I understand.

Comment: Please please know that it’s not pushing folders. The files exist inside a folder. Git deals with files and their locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason it would "push a folder" is if:

- that folder is a nested git repository (it has a `.git/` subfolder in it)
- or that folder is a submodule root folder (the lessons/ parent repository has a `.gitmodules` file in which `lesson1` is declared)

Besides those two use-cases, a git add should add only files, not folder: check what `git status` returns.